# WaitCommEvent Hangs

Tags: c++, winapi

I am using non overlapped WaitCommEvent to read the file data.
I would like to provide a piece of code as follows...

```
SetCommMask (io_ptr->comPortHandles->hComPort, EV_RXCHAR|EV_TXEMPTY);
WaitCommEvent (io_ptr->comPortHandles->hComPort, &dwMask, 0);

if (dwMask &= EV_RXCHAR) {
  // Loop getting data.

  // Need to loop because our buffer is only 1024 bytes
  while (TRUE)
  {
    ClearCommError( io_ptr->comPortHandles->hComPort, &dwError, &comstat);

    if (!comstat.cbInQue) continue;
    else 
    {
      if(comstat.cbInQue > 0)
        ReceiveInterrupt(io_ptr, comstat);
    }
    // Loop around and check for more data
    // In case additional byte has arrived while reading.
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is the `break`? There is no break or exit condition. Did you mean `if (!comstat.cbInQue) break;`?

Comment: hi, break or continue that doesn't matter, real problem is why waitcommevent blocking read thread even after there is no data to read?

Comment: Please format your code snippet.

Comment: I would like to explain more clearly as follows... I am using WaitCommEvent with non overlapped mode, trying to read characters when it is present in Input Queue. The problem here is when there is no char in queue then also WaitCommEvent not breaking. I tried almost every possible condition but still no hope for ending waitcommevent properly if there is no character in the queue, as we know that it is a IOCTL there is less change to end the looping(I tried with CancelIOSync function but didn't get any luck).Please look into that problem if anything possible?

Answer (score 2):

WaitCommEvent is blocking if the file handle was not open with overlapped flag.In you case it will wait until either a char received or last char has been sent.

MSDN about `WaitCommEvent`:

> If hFile was not opened with FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, WaitCommEvent does not return until one of the specified events or an error occurs.

Comment: Thanks. You are right but the thing is that we need to support for both Window CE and Window 7 OS , so for both the cases we aren't able to use FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED. Is there anything else to overcome ?

Comment: Thanks lot .I found three things from my exploration as follows.  1.We cann't break the WaitCommEvent loop as it is an IOCTL. 2.We cann't use CancelIOSync as it only supported by Windows.3.We cann't use overlapped structure as it is only supported by Windows CE. so what could be the generic solution for both CE and Windows using WaitCommEvent.

Comment: Please take a look at this posting, this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956541/serial-i-o-overlapped-non-overlapped-with-windows-windows-ce